Знаки препинания, если прямая речь внутри слов автора
Если вы посмотрите на бутылку и скажете:
«Она наполовину пуста»,— вы пессимист. Если вы скажете:
«Осталась еще половина!», — вы оптимист.
Правильно ли здесь стоят запятая и тире?

Если вы посмотрите на бутылку и скажете: «Она наполовину пуста»,— вы пессимист. Если вы скажете: «Осталась еще половина!» — вы оптимист.
Нам хватит клика внутри кавычек, в редакциях не любят неоправданного нагромождения знаков.
